# I want to create one standalone java application product. is is feasible to use HSQL DB ? cause customer may have very historical data

Tags: java, hsqldb

I want to create a one stanalone product, i.e a standalone java application, and I need a database for that. So I was thinking to use HSQL db.

1. Can HSQLDB is fesible to very historical data like 5 years, 8 years?
2. Is HSQLDB is suitable for that? Or do you know any alternative? (I know MYSQL but I don't want to use MYSQL, I want to use embedded database)

Comment: Can HSQLDB hold a lot of data, most likely, will it perform will, that will depend on your hardware.  H2 might also be worth a look

Comment: How much data do you plan to have here?  Of course, a bona fide separate database might fare better with regard to storage space.

Comment: "8 years" of data doesn't really tell us much. If you create 1000 rows per year in 10 tables, then yes HSQLDB can absolutely cope with that. If you create 10 million rows per year in 1000 tables then I doubt HSQLDB (or any embedded DB) will be able to handle that.